# button delete doesn't execute well in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I'm stuck here again and i don't know where the problem come from !
Well, i have a delete button in c# i wrote the code and everytime i execute it they show a message.box" well deleted" but when i restarted my app i find that nothing has deleted even in my database in sql server ..please tell me what's wrong with my code:

```
 SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter reader = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
        sqlCon.Open();
        string requete = "DELETE FROM [RECAP] where code_reseau='" + textBox1.Text + "' and gch_dep='" + comboBox2.SelectedText + "' and typ_port='" + comboBox3.SelectedText + "' and mois = " +Form3.mois+" and annee = "+Form3.annee+" ";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, sqlCon);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Supprimé !");
        sqlCon.Close();
```

Comment: what is the return value of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`? does it indicate that it deleted anything at all?

Comment: As an aside, you're opening yourself to an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 2):

Are you really sure that the `DELETE` operation succeeded? you are not checking for that and showing the success message. Rather show the message upon checking like

```
   int recordEffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if(recordEffected > 0)
      MessageBox.Show("Supprimé !");
   else
      MessageBox.Show("Maximus Prime !");
```

Comment: I actually tried that and it shows to me "maximus prime" !!! that means my code is wrong or what ?

Comment: @FatimaMounnad, that means nothing has been actually deleted in table and most probably cause none of the record in your table matches the condition you specified in `WHERE` condition

Comment: It's weird! i coded insert button with the same record in the table and it worked ...but this one...no!!!